# How to allow DTD in XML Documents loaded via XSLT's document(uri) function with XslCompiledTransform (.NET)

Tags: .net, xslt

When the `document(uri)` function is used to load another document within the XSLT, where the target document contains a DTD I get an `XslTransformException`, containing an inner `XmlException`:

> For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the ProhibitDtd property on XmlReaderSettings to false and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.

As the `XmlReader` is created within the XSLT implementation there is no direct way to create the XmlReader with the settings I want, and none of the `XslCompiledTransform`, `XmlResolver`<sup>1</sup> or related classes seem to provide any form of hook.

(I'm using a DTD to set some HTML entities to make the authoring of the document easier.)

<sup>1</sup> based on looking at `XmlUrlResolver` in Reflector this just loaded the URI's target as a Stream.

E.g. is the XSLT contains

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('more.xml')/root"/>
```

and `more.xml` contains a DTD then the exception above is the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same `XmlResolver` you pass to the `Transform` method is used for document function, this resolver can return an `XmlReader` that allows DTD, instead of returning `Stream`. You can also return `IXPathNavigable`. In other words, you need a specialized implementation of `XmlResolver` to fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Time for some feedback on the documentation which completely fails to mention you can return something other than Stream.

Comment: @Richard: http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/articles/Introducing_XslCompiledTransform.aspx is the best documentation on XslCompiledTransform.

Comment: They changed the URL, here's the new one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2005/11/16/introducing-xslcompiledtransform.aspx

Comment: And now it's here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/xmlteam/introducing-xslcompiledtransform