# Referencing external named character entities when using XmlReader?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I want to reference an URL having character entities using C#/.NET on an [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=VS.90).aspx) instance, for example [this w3c entity set](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-lat1.ent) defining `&nbsp;` and other chars.

If I were to accomplish it in pure XML it would something like this, or a variation:
`<!ENTITY foo SYSTEM "http://example.org/myent.ent">`

I'm actually **reading fragments of XHTML** source (containing named entities) and therefore need the XML 1.0/[HTML 4](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/) named [Entity Sets defined by w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-A2) to be defined/recognized.
( I'm asking how to *programmatically* reference them on-the-fly while setting up the XmlReader and its Settings for reading fragments; however I'm open to options).

Either way, if I don't include these named entities the reader will cough and produce .NET errors such as the following XmlException for `&nbsp;` and other non-numeric entities:

> Test 'Xml_Tester.Test_Reading' failed:
>   System.Xml.XmlException : Reference to
>   undeclared entity 'nbsp'. Line 6,
>   position 393.

*Note*: I'm successfully referencing an [XHTML Schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1-schema/#schemas) using the [XmlReaderSettings.Schemas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.schemas.aspx) collection property, and assume there has to be an equally easy way to call in external entity references without modifying the XML source, but it evades me.

---

### Etc:

I've come across the following significant info bits while searching for an answer -they're  likely useful here ...

**Support for entities**
To use entities, authors have to use the DTD mechanism. See section 1.5 to use DTD and XML Schema together.
-- http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1-schema/#diffs

**1.5. Using DTD and XML Schema together**
DTD validation and XML Schema validation are not mutually exclusive. Sometimes authors might want to use some DTD features (e.g. entities) while taking advantage of the XML Schema validation.
-- http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1-schema/#together

**Combining XML Documents with XInclude**
External entities must be declared in a DTD or an internal subset. This opens a Pandora's Box full of implications, such as the fact that the document element must be named in Doctype declaration and that validating readers may require that the full content model of the document be defined in DTD among others.
-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302291.aspx#xinc_topic1

Comment: My question about using a DTD with an XmlReader you don't directly create might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451704/how-to-allow-dtd-in-xml-documents-loaded-via-xslts-documenturi-function-with-x

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I actually came to an answer which is posted below almost in entirety. I hope people continue to post alternate answers and suggestions. The world of XML is very broad, almost too much for my taste when trying to cobble some things together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer to **use XMLReader instance to read XHTML source that includes named entities like `&nbsp;` without throwing an XmlException**

To start I copied the following XML sample directly from W3C's page: XHTML 1.0 in XML Schema, section [**1.5. Using DTD and XML Schema together**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1-schema/#together) in support of bringing in  the named entity chars and having Schema based validation at the same time:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"[
<!ATTLIST html
    xmlns:xsi CDATA #FIXED "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation CDATA #IMPLIED
>
]>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
                          http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd">
  ...
</html>
```

and am **substituting  XHTML fragments** e.g. `<body><div><b>xhtml stuff</b></div></body>` into the location of `...` in the above sample.

This successfully mixes DTD (to reference named entities) with Schema validation. The  XMLReader no longer throws an XMLExeption when a named entity is encountered.
Success!

---

The **C#.NET code** that processes the above sample

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
```

The core logic follows. **Note**: This is copied and pasted verbatim. Some of the settings might be frivolous or redundant so you can tweak to achieve various other mileage.

```
XmlReaderSettings settingsXRdr = new XmlReaderSettings();
settingsXRdr.ProhibitDtd = false;
settingsXRdr.CheckCharacters = true;
settingsXRdr.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;
settingsXRdr.IgnoreProcessingInstructions = false;
settingsXRdr.IgnoreComments = false;
settingsXRdr.XmlResolver = new CustomXmlResolver();
settingsXRdr.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;

// This is a format string; notice the placeholder {0} where the fragment will be injected:

string mixFmtString1 = @"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"" ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd""[
<!ATTLIST html
xmlns:xsi CDATA #FIXED ""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""
xsi:schemaLocation CDATA #IMPLIED
>
]>
<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"" lang=""en"" xml:lang=""en""
xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""
xsi:schemaLocation=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
              http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd"">
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<div>{0}</div>
</body>
</html>";


// Inject any well-formed fragment via the second argument
string xhtml = string.Format(mixFmtString1, "<b>Xhtml fragment w/named entity: &nbsp;</b>");

// Creates a validating reader (derived type) because of the above settings)
XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xhtml), settingsXRdr);

// Reads the entire XHTML document (validating it along the way).
while (rdr.Read()) {

    // Do whatever you want here for each piece processed.
    var dummy = rdr.NodeType.ToString();  // Access a string value for fun.
    // If you just want validation to occur then leave this an empty code block. 

}
```

Note: This solution uses the Strict template for XHTML so certain deprecated tags like `<center>` will fail the reader. You might want to reformulate the referenced items to point to the more forgiving [loose XHTML template](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/loosedtd.html).

Related/useful resources from along the way:

- Similar problem, solved a different way: [Reference to undeclared entity exception while working with XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281682/)